# How to install pyzmq "--with-pgm"

Tags: python, zeromq, multicast, pyzmq

I have zmq version 4.1.3 and pyzmq version 15.2.0 installed on my machine (I assume through pip but I dont remember now).  I have a need to connect to a UDP epgm socket but get the error "protocol not supported".  I have searched the vast expanses of the internet and have found the answer: "build zero mq with `--with-pgm` option".

Does anyone know how to do that?

I searched around the harddrive and found the zeromq library in pkgs in my python directory and found some .so files but I dont see any setup.py or anything to recompile with the mysterious `--with-pgm` option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general procedure which works for me:
1. download zeromq package (using zeromq-4.1.5.tar.gz as example)
2. `tar zxvf zeromq-4.1.5.tar.gz`
3. `cd zeromq-4.1.5`
4. `apt-get install libpgm-dev`
5. `./configure --with-pgm && make && make install`
6. `pip install --no-binary :all: pyzmq`

Then you can use pgm/epgm as you want.